# Show $(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ converges to $c$ iff $(a_n)_{n=m'}^{\infty}$ does.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, cauchy-sequences

Is my proof correct?
Let $(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $c$ be  real number. and let $m' \geq m$ be an integer. Show $(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ converges to $c$ iff $(a_n)_{n=m'}^{\infty}$ converges to $c$.

proof:

if $(a_n)_{n=m'}^{\infty}$ converges to c,
$$ \exists N\geq m' \text{ s. t. } |a_n-c|\leq \epsilon$$
since $m'\geq m$, then the following statement is true:
$$ \exists N\geq m \text{ s. t. } |a_n-c|\leq \epsilon$$
and hence$(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty}$converges to c.

if $(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ converges to c,
$$ \exists N\geq m \text{ s. t. } |a_n-c|\leq \epsilon$$
$N$ can be $$m\leq N\leq m'$$ or $$N\geq m'$$
for case 2 the following statement will be true:
$$ \exists N\geq m' \text{ s. t. } |a_n-c|\leq \epsilon$$ 
for case 1, we can pick N=m' and hence $(a_n)_{n=m}$ converges

Answer (score 0):

The proof is correct............

Comment: Could you add some details to this answer?